# linq to xml iterate through results

Tags: xml, linq, loops

I'm new to using linq in particular linq to xml and am having trouble trying to iterate through the results. My xml document has multiple nodes of the same name nested in a single parent node and I have used the following linq query which returns the correct result set.

```
var listingAgentElements = from p in _xElement.Descendants("commercial") select p.Elements("listingAgent");
```

My xml has the following format:

```
<commercial>
    <listingAgent id="1">
    <listingAgent id="2">
    <listingAgent id="3">
 </commercial>
```

I am getting a result set containing all of the listing agents although for some reason when I try do the following foreach loop over listingAgentElements each element I try to loop over seems to have exactly the same result set as in still has all three listingAgents:

```
foreach (var element in listingAgentElements)
{
    var test = element;
}
```

Each listingAgent has a set of child elements in which I would like to loop over and get the values of to store in a DB as I'm doing an xml import console app.

It appears that their may be a problem with the query but I'm really not sure, could someone please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so from what you've posted, it looks like your `listingAgentElements` actually contains 2 enumerables - one comes from `_xElement.Descendants("commercial")` (even if there's only one, `.Descendants` returns an enumerable list), and the second from `.Elements("listingAgent")`

I'd hazard a guess and say that from the XML you posted, your `for` loop is only running through once? This means it's looping through the enumerable for `_xElement.Descendants` and hence `commercial` is actually another enumerable containing all 3 listingAgents.

If your XML only has one "commercial" tag, I'd get that using `.Element("commercial")`, or if it's the root of your XElement object then don't even bother with that part.

So the options are:
If you just have one "commercial" tag, and your `_xElement` is **in fact** an XElement representing this, use:

```
   var listingAgentElements =  from p in _xElement
                               select p.Elements("listingAgent");
```

If you have one "commercial" tag but it is not the root of your `_xElement` then use:

```
   var listingAgentElements =  from p in _xElement.Element("commercial")
                               select p.Elements("listingAgent");
```

If you just have one "commercial" tag, and your `_xElement` is **actually an `XDocument`** , use:

```
   var listingAgentElements =  from p in _xElement.Root
                               select p.Elements("listingAgent");
```

If you have multiple "commercial" tags, use the original query but loop over it twice, for example:

```
    foreach (var commercial in listingAgentElements)
    {
        foreach (var element in commercial)
        {
            var test = element;
        }
    }
```

One of these solutions should provide you with a list of the listingAgents you require. If you need any clarification post a comment and I'll edit the answer as necessary.

As an aside, I'd look at the formatting of your XML - if you've copy/pasted this, you need to be closing your `listingAgent` tags, with either `<listingAgent id="1" />` or `<listingAgent id="1"></listingAgent>`. Now you did mention that your listingAgent contains more tags, so I'm assuming you've just cut the code down to post only the relevant parts, but just something you might need to keep an eye on. (If you're using Linq2XML to create your XMLs, this will be handled automatically anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Use `SelectMany` to flatten `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>>` to `IEnumerable<XElement>`:

```
var listingAgentElements =  from p in _xElement.Descendants("commercial")
                            from l in p.Elements("listingAgent")
                            select l;
```

Or in method-based syntax:

```
var listingAgentElements = _xElement.Descendants("commercial")
                                    .SelectMany(p => p.Elements("listingAgent");
```

Iterating over that kind of query results will give you all `<listingAgent>` elements.